# Put an image on another image

Tags: c#, image, .net-core

I'm currently using the below code to put an image on top of another image

```
Stream stream = client.OpenRead(some URL here);
Bitmap baseimg = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
Bitmap ovlimg = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("fanmade.png");
var finalImage = new Bitmap(baseimg.Width, baseimg.Height);
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(finalImage);
graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver;

graphics.DrawImage(baseimg, 0, 0);
graphics.DrawImage(ovlimg, 0, 0);
                
finalImage.Save("1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

However, the file size turns out to be a lot bigger than expected from 6-9 Mb to 16Mb. So I'm trying to find a more efficient way that would make the file size smaller while still keeping the image quality

Here are both the images

The Base IMG (Changes based on the user input but here's an example): https://pasteboard.co/K6hCXng.png

The overlay IMG: https://pasteboard.co/K6hDvIc.png

Comment: Without knowing more/seeing the images we can hardly comment on the issue. The code looks ok. Were both original files PNG files? Did you control the dpi resolutions?

Comment: @TaW Both original files are PNG files. I did not control dpi resolutions. The base img is at 6-7 MB while the overlay image is only at 300 KB.

Comment: Does the result look right?

Comment: @TaW The result is completely fine. The only thing out of place would be the size of the file

Comment: It has nothing to do with overlaying; you can save the 1st file directly and it will have the same size. So, for the time being it looks as if the orginal file was incoded/compressed extremely well..